# In groovy, how to remove the default value of a property which is set as Double?

Tags: groovy, double, default

I just wanted to know if there is a way on how to remove the default value of the input field of a property which has a Double datatype. The default value in the input field is 0.0, I wanted to remove that, but I don't know how? Any help from you?
Thanks!

Comment: groovy, input field => swing... are you using griffon? Please post some code to get better help.

Comment: I am using grails as a platform, groovy as a language..thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by calling the .toString() method upon saving the value of the property..